# Java Executor service callable returns hashing errors

Tags: java, executorservice, callable

I have problem in Java multithreadig **Executor service**. I have Implemented Callable for a multithreading task. According to my knowledge I do not have to use any concurrentHashMap or SynchronisedMap for put() because none of two threads are using same Map.
  My question is that if my thread uses a nested method to obtain result could this be a problem. My code is like this:

```
public TreeMap2 method3 implements Callable(TreeMap1){
    TreeMap2 = method2(TreeMap1);
    return TreeMap2
}

public TreeMap2 method2(TreeMap1){
    TreeMap = method1(TreeMap1)
    //Do some work
    return TreeMap2
}


public TreeMap method1(TreeMap1){
    // Do some work
    return TreeMap;
}
```

The whole task is then divided into 4 threads and invoked by InvokeAll. But this throws error related to Hashing which are like:

```
Exception on pipe 27. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 563893
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 563893
at gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap.rehash(TObjectIntHashMap.java:171)
at gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:243)
at gnu.trove.TObjectIntHashMap.put(TObjectIntHashMap.java:148)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.types.Alphabet.lookupIndex(Alphabet.java:107)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.types.AugmentableFeatureVector.<init>(AugmentableFeatureVector.java:88)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.types.FeatureVectorSequence.<init>(FeatureVectorSequence.java:39)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.pipe.TokenSequence2FeatureVectorSequence.pipe(TokenSequence2FeatureVectorSequence.java:60)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.pipe.SerialPipes.pipe(SerialPipes.java:141)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.pipe.SerialPipes.pipe(SerialPipes.java:217)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.types.Instance.<init>(Instance.java:105)
at edu.umass.cs.mallet.base.types.InstanceList.add(InstanceList.java:741)
at de.bonn.limes.gcam.abner.MyTagger.doTagging(MyTagger.java:445)
at de.bonn.limes.gcam.abner.MyTagger.getEntities(MyTagger.java:297)
at de.bonn.limes.core.AbnerAnalysis.NERanalysis(AbnerAnalysis.java:84)
at de.bonn.limes.core.AbstractTagger.tagAbstracts(AbstractTagger.java:62)
at de.bonn.limes.core.ListOperations$AbnerCallable.call(ListOperations.java:51)
at de.bonn.limes.core.ListOperations$AbnerCallable.call(ListOperations.java:38)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My original post is [Java Executor service concurrency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652149/java-executor-service-concurrency-issue).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please put real java code.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652149/java-executor-service-concurrency-issue

Comment: This code does not compile

Comment: You can use the `edit`button instead of posting a new question.

Comment: This will not compile because there are other dependencies. When I run this code in single thread it compiles on my system. This code does multi-threading for an text mining task. So it's not feasible to give everything here.

Comment: I know, but that post gone cold so I had to initialize new thread.